# How do I refresh the database annually?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am storing the user information in my database along with other attributes such as his annual leave/vacation balance.

The user annual leave would be 14 days every year but I want to refresh it every year and add another 14 to it. If the user had 3 days of annual leave left at year's end, then he would start the new year with a 17 day balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [percolate:synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron) package to create an annual job to update such balances.

You might also need a `lastUpdatedDate` to make sure you don't accidentally add to the balance twice. You have to anticipate any errors that would leave your data partially-updated.